# C# String regex: Word with single space only

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regular expression `@"^[a-zA-Z ]+$"`. The idea was given [replace `_` with ]`string_string`, `stringstring`, `string__string` must return `True`, `True`, `False`.

What is the proper regular expression to accept a string input only accepting alphabets and a single space [only space].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid the prefix with a trick

```
^([a-zA-Z]+ ?)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
 [a-zA-Z]+ ?[a-zA-Z]+
```

This would match what you want, but in string__string match both strings.

Assuming one line, you can add ^$ back like you did before for entire line matching, then 3 wouldn't match at all.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+ {0,1}[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Which is the same as

```
^[a-zA-Z]+ ?[a-zA-Z]+$
```